# Can I get out of my question ban by answers?

Tags: discussion, support, post-ban

I have been banned from the privilege of asking questions on Stack Overflow. It has been a few days since then.

In those days I have tried a lot of things: I have answered many questions, made edits, earned 2 silver badges, and edited almost all of my negative voted questions.

I am running out of ideas. If I try to delete one my questions, there is a pop up saying that it won't help getting my privilege back.

I also tried summing up all my question votes and it came out to be 12. Also, it was stated that time won't help getting out of the block.

So I was wondering what to do:

- Does answering help getting out of this?
- Does earning badges help?
- Does editing others questions/answers help?

I am extremely sorry for what I have done to get into this ban, but what can I do now to get out of it?

Also, how much hard work do I need to invest? I am asking this, because I tried some things and still every time I try ask a question, it shows the same message. Am I already close to my goal or is there still a very long road ahead?

Comment: Do you have deleted questions?  Either self deleted ones or questions deleted by moderators or the community.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I don't remember deleting questions, some of my questions had/have been on hold or closed but in near past I have not deleted questions, neither have moderators

Comment: Look at **all** your questions. Not just the ones that have been downvoted. Those with zero score that you can improve (add detail or improve in any way) as well. Perhaps look at those with upvotes and improve on them. Any **positive** contribution to the site (that includes good answers) will take you closer to getting out of the ban.

Comment: In the answer to [your other question related to this issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252723/3524344), all of the information you need (and, indeed, all the information that is available) is in an [article in the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans), and you were already referred there.

Comment: @3524344 I tried a lot of things after that, still with no luck thats why I asked this specific question

Comment: @DakshShah don't just focus on improving your downvoted questions.  You have numerous questions with no net score, and presumably many have zero votes.  Upvotes on those questions can help too.  Basically anything you can do to improve your overall contributions to the site will help.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I also get this ban this morning and I do have a lot deleted questions. I believe that's the reason I am banned. When I asked a question and solved it before I got answer, I always delete it. I never know it has negative effects. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: @zhangjinzhou self deletes after you get an answer apparently one of the worst things you can do towards the question ban (but no one truly knows the exact impact except the development team), but that is considered a hostile act since you are wasting someone's contributions.  If you undelete them, it should help

Comment: @psubsee2003 I just did it but I still have the ban. Do you know how long soon will my changes effect?

Comment: @zhangjinzhou it is immediate, assuming all you needed to do is undelete the deleted questions.  The algorithm might still have you banned, based on the quality of the contributions.  Keep in mind, that your profile (under "deleted recent items" only shows the last 90 days.  If you have made a habit of this over over an extended period, you may have more deleted questions that you can't see unless you saved the link somewhere.  Only a moderator would be able to help you find the older deleted questions.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I started using stackoverflow less than 1 month ago. Fortunately all my deleted items are still there. Will be keep improving questions and answers to get rid of it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @zhangjinzhou given you have no visible negatively score questions at all, I'm guessing there is something else dragging you down (like some downvoted questions that are still deleted).  You need to earn more rep by improving your existing questions (try to get some up-votes) and/or trying to fix any negatively scored deleted questions.  I can't help you any more though, so you'll need a mod or a preferably a community manager to assist you to understand the ban, if you really don't understand the why

Comment: @psubsee2003 I do have a couple deleted downvoted questions. Should I undelete them?

Comment: After undeleted questions with downvotes, the ban was removed! I am guessing deleting a post is even worse than having downvotes. Thank you @psubsee2003

Comment: Is there a difference in treatment when deleting  a question with downvotes if a user does it or if the system does it ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You *can*. It's probably not going to be easy though. I see too many people go at this by half-heartedly tossing a few brief answers onto already-answered questions... Guess what: if you're not actually adding *significant* value to the site, going through the motions ain't gonna help.

As always, your *best* option for lifting the quality ban is to **fix whatever the community thought was of low or middling quality!**

But if you prefer to spend your time helping others, and actually *do* help lots of other people, that can also help.

Comment: YEP, EARN IT BABY!!

Comment: Just one last doubt, could you tell me am I close? or not?

Comment: Closer than you were.

Comment: hope is restored.

Comment: @Shog - Parallel to this issue. This user hit the ban, but instead of just re-rolling they are actually fixing their content. It is fairly clear that is because they are already invested in this account. I know there is automagic in the ban process, but is there a way to get users who are banned to still feel invested in their accounts so they don't just bypass the ban?

Comment: @Travis J: That is up to them - the site gives them all the guidance they need in order to help themselves.

Comment: Sure, @Travis. Let's face it: Daksh has a pretty respectable-looking account at this point, due in large part to the work he's put in to try and lift the ban. It could be *better* - see my note about answering questions that actually need answers - but even so, still something he should be proud of. If he wishes to give that up, that's a shame.

Comment: I had a question ban once, after I started answering I found that I was actually learning more from replying to questions.

Comment: @Shog9 - Do you think [throttling posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230857/178816) as opposed to halting them could improve the ban functionality by allowing users to have the same feeling of investment?

Comment: Yes, I do, @Travis. This is something we've been talking about for a long time; we have initial designs in place, and will start rolling out pieces / talking more about this publicly in the near future.

Answer (score 18):

> Does answering help getting out of this?

By itself, no.  If you get upvotes on them, then yes.

> Does earning badges help?

Directly, no, but badges are generally awarded for doing good things, which may have an effect on your post ban.

> Does editing others questions/answers help?

If they're accepted, yes.  To what degree is unknown though.