# What are positive contributions that users can make to be removed from question bans?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

Would the system classify all of these as positive contributions?

1. Code formatting (edit)
2. Grammar editting (edit)
3. Editing single spelling mistake (edit)
4. Editing `Question formating (e.g. line breaking in questions, etc)` (edit)

Or what else, will be considered positive contribution?

Comment: Answers (upvoted ones) would be positive contributions, too.

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253116/can-i-get-out-of-my-question-ban-by-answers

Comment: You appear to mostly be making suggested edits to other people's posts... This doesn't improve the quality of your own posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) says this:

> All questions are expected to be useful to future visitors, too, so put effort into writing with *proper grammar and spelling*, *formatting* your post so it can be *read easily*, and providing as much detail as possible about your problem and what you have already tried.

I believe that covers your four bullet points. The overall goal is to make the posts easy to read and understand, anything that helps in this respect is a good idea. Trimming down posts with too much irrelevant information can help too, if it helps focus on the exact problem. Adding more details if there weren't enough to diagnose at first will help too.

You say:

> Would **the system** classify all of these as positive contributions?

"The system" in this case is (mostly) the community of people who frequent these sites. There probably are some automated quality checks too, but don't think you'll get out of it by just increasing some mechanical metrics.

If you're trying to get a ban lifted, the most important thing to do is to transform posts that were not well received into posts that *are* well received *by the community*, i.e. humans. This transformation should, in the long run, garner positive votes on said posts (a sign that people find them useful), which is (probably) the most important factor in the decision to automatically lift a ban or not.

Remember that deleted posts do count in the ban evaluation. If you have some that you think can be made to fit better, take care of those too. You can flag those once you're done editing to get a moderator to review and possibly undelete them. (You can find your recently deleted posts via a link in your profile at the bottom of the Answers or Questions tabs.)

Besides editing existing posts, providing quality answers [can help lifting a question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253116/can-i-get-out-of-my-question-ban-by-answers), but that doesn't have as much impact as improving existing posts does. (I suspect the same is true for posting good questions when faced with an answer ban.)

Comment: It seems that it is more difficult to lift the question ban than before. I had one newly accepted answer, edited my questions five times today (I couldn't do more), edited the others questions about ten times, provided three quality answers, and the ban was not lifted.

Comment: What happens if you asked two totally awful question, I mean really awful, and can't fix them.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms See [BoltClock's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280876/2738262).