# Necessary Contribution to Remove Question Ban

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I was banned from asking questions with a reputation of around 40. I have been marked the correct answer on two questions, and edited several others resulting in over doubling my reputation (101). Is there a way to calculate how much I need to contribute or if I'm contributing in the right place or is there nothing I can do to figure it out?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253695/what-are-positive-contributions-that-users-can-make-to-be-removed-from-question?rq=1

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253116/can-i-get-out-of-my-question-ban-by-answers?rq=1

Comment: My advice is to use bootstrap.  Lots of your css questions would be easily solved if you stopped [fiddling with the blinds](http://i.stack.imgur.com/H375C.gif) and use a css framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual formula for determining a post-ban is purposefully kept a secret. This is to prevent people from "gaming" the system by doing *barely* enough to stay out of a ban.

Not even elected Community Moderators can tell you how close you are to being banned or being freed of a ban, so no, you can't calculate it either.

The single best thing you can do is to improve your existing questions so that they get positive votes. But nobody except the developers can tell you exactly what you need to do (and they won't tell you).