# Earned 152 rep today, and I'm still banned from asking questions

Tags: discussion, reputation, post-ban

I'm not sure what's going on, but I've been banned from asking questions for a while now, and today I recently decided to try and get unbanned.

I heard from my friend that if you answer good questions, you can get yourself unbanned. So I answered a few questions, and I unlocked some stuff, and I earned 152 reputation.

So I went to see if I was unbanned, and I was still banned. I thought: *unbelievable*.

So I went here to ask if I'm on the right track.

Comment: The association bonus does not apply towards the question ban, so it's more like 50 reputation rather than 150. I'll take a look at the rest of your posts though.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy The reason I'm banned from posting is because I have a lot of flagged questions, questions that I cannot fix.

Comment: By "flagged", I assume you mean "deleted"? [Fixing your old questions is really the best approach to lifting the ban](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253118/366904), though.

Comment: I have a feeling this: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20830755/revisions may have something to do with it.

Comment: @Mat, sorry if that felt disrespectful, it wasn't intended too. So I removed it.

Comment: @BenAaronson, Oh...  Any idea how I would fix that? :L

Comment: @Mat, fixed it again, sorry.

Comment: @Xero Nope. You'll have to wait for somebody better informed than me

Comment: @Xero, since you reverted my edit your title still contradicts your question. Are you banned from asking or from answering? Or maybe both?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Omg that was a huge mistake, I meant **asking** questions.

Comment: Tell me something. **If you were under a question ban, how exactly did you ask this question?**

Comment: @ProgyadeepMoulik Are you able to ask questions on meta still when you are question banned?  If not, I'm unsure how I was able to.  But this question is almost 2 years old, and the ban is long gone.

Comment: @Jamen I am banned from asking questions on Stack Overflow. I can ask questions elsewhere. Since the ban, I've earned a 100 bonus rep on every SE site (due to my activity on SO), gained 8 bronze and 2 silver badges and 90% of my answers have been upvoted and/or marked as correct answer. I still am banned. What more should I do?

Comment: @ProgyadeepMoulik Try answering some questions, or editing your posted questions.  The 100 bonus rep does not count towards overcoming a ban.

Comment: I'll keep doing it as I have; can you please tell me how long did it take for your question ban to be lifted as a result of your good answers? I've already been banned for over a month.

Comment: @ProgyadeepMoulik I can't quite remember.  It definitely didn't take me more than month to get over it though.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Keep in mind that nobody knows the banning formula. It is thought to involve:

- the average score of all your questions
- the worst question score you have
- what fraction of your questions have been deleted (whether by you or others)
- your overall reputation

It is known not to involve:

- time (how long you've been a member, how long you've been banned, how quickly your downvotes accumulated)

You have worked on your overall reputation and that hasn't lifted the ban. It might for some people, but it hasn't for you. You've also waited, which never works for anyone.

What you need to do is work on your questions. If you have deleted ones, that you believe can't be saved because they're just so offtopic for the site, then work on your non deleted ones. You have two questions with more downvotes than upvotes. One of them contains absolutely no code, no what you've tried so far, no what's happening that you don't like, just "I want to change this to this." You can totally edit that into a better question. The other doesn't belong here, so you probably are stuck with it (deleting it would make things worse.)

Then you have a ton of questions with zero votes. Look critically at them. Look at highly upvoted questions in the same tag. What do those questions have that you don't? Are you including too much code? Not enough? Burying the actual question in a pile of background? Omitting the background? Figure it out. You have questions that you can edit and improve, and when you have done so, you'll be able to ask again. What the system is telling you now is that you really just can't be bothered to be good at asking questions. You just ask whatever comes into your head and don't put thought into it. The only way out of the ban is to put a lot of thought into your questions, and make them good questions. Edit the ones you've already asked and see what happens next.

Comment: This is a very good explanation. Thanks!