# Why did my answers get deleted?

Tags: support, answers, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I have posted answer to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25784763/3531606

Then I copied the answer to several related questions. However, all of them got deleted. I'm failing to see how they broke the rules from https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers - the original answer is linked, only the most vital part is copied in order to make it easier for reader to repair the bug.

Anyway, I rephrased the answers and flag some of them to re-evaluate by moderator, for example

- [Applications hangs and touch events does not work in Samsung devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585405/applications-hangs-and-touch-events-does-not-work-in-samsung-devices/25785652#25785652)
- [What does blockWebkitDraw mean and how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032616/what-does-blockwebkitdraw-mean-and-how-to-fix-it/25784698#25784698)

Unfortunately, they are still deleted. What am I doing wrong? Is it not good to link the question to similar, already solved problem? What should I change in order to create good answers?

Comment: Don't copy-paste answers even if they are your own. If multiple questions can be answered with the exact same answers, the questions are likely duplicates and you should flag them for closure.

Comment: @Mysticial: He posted two answers there. The second one suggests closing as duplicate, which is for flags (and maybe comments), not answers.

Comment: Well, It seems one needs 15 reputation in order to be able flag duplicate (or so they say in http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118126). Whooping 50 reputation needed for comment... It seemed to me that the only thing I can do is to post a link to answered question. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Lukas, in that case, the best bet is to just leave it be until you have the rep to flag/comment. You will _always_ receive backlash for using the answers to link to a duplicate. You could bookmark the question or favorite it to be able to find it later to flag/comment when you have the rep. :)

Comment: Thanks for advice guys. It seems that I am banned and cant post answers anymore which means no more reputation for me until some moderator undeletes my edited answers. I didn't expect stack overflow to be so harsh to newcomers though...

Comment: @Lukas, to be honest we did not expect newcomers to believe copy-pasting the same answer around was a good thing either.

Comment: Yea, I just thought it would help ... I found the unanswered question first, and the solved question much later. Thus, I just copy-pasted linked answer for others to find (as there is nothing about copy-pasting being wrong at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Anyway, I learned from my mistake now (probably too late), so do You think there is something I could do to improve the edited answers further?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, why would anyone normally think it was a bad thing to answer multiple questions with the same correct answer?

Comment: @Lance, come on, you know which way the community swings. The mere fact nobody else is doing it should be strong enough a hint that posting repeated instances of `I had a similar problem [...] I found the solution in this answer` with a link to another answer is not a very good idea.

Comment: Sure, but he also pulled the important info out, as you're supposed to do with links. I thought it was a well-done answer, though I couldn't just the technical accuracy of it.

Comment: You made a good start by coming to Meta to ask. Also, now you have enough rep to flag. So, flagging is the correct option.

Comment: Well, it seems that I need 50 rep to flag duplicate (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217253). Now I see that flagging is the correct action here. But when the questions will be marked as duplicate, undeleting my answers will not make sense anymore. Thus, my account will become practically banned forever from posting answers, am I right?

Comment: Bans can be lifted if you make positive contributions to the site. All positive contributions count. Watch the front page, lots of posts need editing help with typos, code block formatting and removing thanks-regards-please help etc. Make good edits and try to fix all issues in the posts. You get 2 rep for each helpful edit upto a max of 1000 rep from suggesting edits. Also, flag all off-topic questions that ask for tutorials, libraries and book recommendations. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253116/can-i-get-out-of-my-question-ban-by-answers.

Comment: Code block formatting tip: select the code and press ctrl+k

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Why wouldn't newcomers think that posting the same answer to multiple questions would be a good thing? Likely they thought they were helping the original questioners by dispersing this information.

Comment: Damn right. And if I think I'm helping by swerving to the left in order to leave room for a motorist, and by doing that cause trouble for drivers going the other way, and basically make everyone's life miserable in the process, it's still my fault, @Martin.

Answer (score -15):

Some mods don't like copy-pasted answers even if they answer the question. If you do a bunch of it the system flags you and then they will delete them despite the fact that they answer the question. If your answer accurately answers those questions, don't answer them all at once.  Kinda like don't make too many edits, even if needed all at once, as it floods the front page and irritates people.

I'm figuring the context will usually be different enough that it will need to be modified. **But what matters is that the question gets a good answer, I'm not going to worry about whether something is a copy or not; I'm going to help people.**

Comment: Thanks for advice Lance, I'll be wiser next time. So do suggest that it could be a good idea to flag the answers to moderator for undelete one by one with some days in between? Or should I expand/rewrite the answers some more? (I dont think I can elaborate on the technical reason of the android webview bug, but the solution works for me)

Comment: You could try that.  I flagged the first one, not sure if it will get any play or not.

Comment: It has nothing to do with "some mods". It has to do with the fact that if the same exact answer can be posted to several questions, they must be duplicates and should be flagged as such. Copy/pasting the same answer is not appropriate; it might be acceptable to do so once in a rare circumstance, but it's never appropriate to do so several times. There is absolutely no benefit to having several copies of the same question (and answer) here when one supplies the information.

Comment: I'm figuring the context will usually be different enough that it will need to be modified.  But what matters is that the question gets a good answer, I'm not going to worry about whether something is a copy or not.

Comment: If people actually took the time to tailor their answers according to context, we wouldn't be deleting the answers to begin with. But how often do you see people doing that? This particular user had to be prompted by flags and deletions before they did that (and it was an *automatic* flag, mind you, which means the user originally pasted those answers with *no changes* whatsoever). A few other users we've dealt with have done the same - only after the fact - and the majority of others simply don't care. And *somebody* has to care.

Comment: To date, I think I've twice re-posted one of my answers verbatim. Though I then tailored it immediately... (And only because it was a valid answer to both questions, but they actually were not duplicates of each other.)

Comment: It's sad that so many long-time users of this site don't recognize that there are many questions that aren't exact duplicates, but can be answered with the same answer.