# Answer deletion on Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: support, meta, vote-to-delete

According to the [privilege page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), a trusted user should be able to vote to delete answers with a score of -1 or lower. The prior link is to Meta Stack Overflow privileges, but that just redirects to the Stack Overflow privileges page.

The scores below are correct at the time of writing, but may change due to the meta effect.

- I can vote to delete this [-10 answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271281/why-did-my-answers-get-deleted/271297#271297) or this [-8 answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291531/many-question-askers-seem-to-only-want-the-code-not-to-understand-how-to-solve/291724#291724) on these open questions
- I cannot vote to delete this [-4 answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281350/why-not-to-force-members-to-leave-comments-when-they-downvote/281351#281351) or this [-7 answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276012/dealing-with-a-claim-that-a-post-on-so-is-using-copyrighted-content-without-perm/276140#276140) on these open questions

So the Meta Stack Overflow rule is that an answer must be -8 before I can vote to delete as documented in [Shog's answer to this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267969/are-we-abusing-our-delete-votes-on-meta). Shouldn't the trusted user privilege page make this clear?

Is it the same on all Meta sites except for Meta Stack Exchange?

Comment: If I had to guess, it's a result of whatever code is used to shift bad-answer graying on child metas from -3 to -10 -- that is, by `-7`.

Comment: No, as I explain in the question it's a result of deliberate moderator action. The question is about documenting that more clearly.

Comment: I thought meta votes are about agreeing and disagreeing. If someone makes a meta question "Burninate [c++]" and people heavily downvote it it is still a useful question that should not be deleted.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that answers should be deleted, I'm saying that the fact that an answer needs to be -8 should be better documented that's all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it the same on all Meta sites except for Meta Stack Exchange?

We just encountered [this confusion on the Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6659673#6659673), and it seems *this is exclusive to Meta Stack Overflow*.

Based on experiences from Meta Stack Exchange regulars (Shadow Wizard & rene), and Anime & Manga regular (me), as of current writing, the score for an answer on meta to be eligible to be deleted:

- -1 on MSE ("meta" site)
- -1 on Meta.Anime.SE (general child meta)
- -8 only on MSO (as per this meta question)