# Should we allow accepted answers to be deleted?

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, accepted-answer

Accepted answers aren't the community's decision: it's an option by the OP. If the answer breaks the website rules, it makes sense to be deleted, but why can't the OP see the accepted answer anymore?

As a community, we cannot accept answers for a question. But we can remove accept from an answer, by deleting that answer. This is counter-intuitive: Is answer accepting meant to be community-driven, or not?

It would make sense if we allow the OP to see deleted answers, or at least accepted deleted answers.

In fact, not allowing accepted answers to be deleted makes sense too: Edits can always be added, and edit history preserves the original answer from being lost from the OP.

Comment: My understanding is that only moderators can delete accepted answers, and that regular users can't do so. It's certainly not a power to be used lightly, nor (from experience) is it very commonly used: I think I can count the number of occasions I've seen it happen on the fingers of one hand.

Comment: @F1Krazy can moderators also add accepted answers?

Comment: No, only the user who posted the question can accept an answer to it. A moderator can, of course, post an answer that the OP then accepts, but that's probably not what you meant.

Comment: It might make sense to split the two separate features into separate requests. Allowing users to completely block deletion is an entirely different thing than allowing individual users to see answers they could see previously. Note that voting on meta can include agreement and disagreement with feature requests, so an unacceptable request can drag an otherwise acceptable one down with it if combined.

Comment: You accept an answer to your question. While you're away the answer is edited by the answerer into a rude slur on yourself. We helpfully delete that answer (because we can). Should we a) not be allowed to or b) we can and do delete it but you are forced to see that rude deleted answer every time you look at your question.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi currently, you can remove an accepted answer from OP. That's the weird part. You would imagine the answer is accepted because OP finds it useful. Therefore even the most understandable removal can sabotage the OP.

Comment: Alternatively one user by accepting their answer or someone else's could sabotage the site and only by waiting for a moderator could we fix that. Of course you can undelete anything by asking a moderator to do it for you.

Comment: @ingotangjingle I don't see how that is relevant for my comment.

Comment: @RobertLongson You cannot vote to undelete an accepted answer. You're avoiding the question here,  Why can't the OP just decide for themselves what to accept?

Comment: You can flag for undeletion as I explain in my answer. You can't keep rude answers on the site simply by accepting them.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi either the accepting system is for the OP, or it's for the community. Currently, it's not for either, because OP can decide to not accept useful answers, and community can remove answers OP finds useful.

Comment: @RobertLongson You cannot see deleted accepted answers.

Comment: If you've accepted it, you know it was there. You don't need to see it to custom flag your question.

Comment: @ingotangjingle *Everything* on SO is for the community first. Even accepting is there to signal *to the community* what the OP considered correct. It's not a bookmark or protective spell for the OP to wield.

Comment: There's quite of bit of misunderstanding here. Accepting an answer does bock deletion by the answer author. It does not block any other type of deletion (e.g., by spam or R/A flags, votes from other users, deletion by moderators). The fact that an answer was accepted has no effect on if it can or can't be undeleted or voted to be undeleted.

Comment: @Makyen yes. that's the issue: Accepted answer can be deleted by a community decision, but accepted answers are decided by OP, regardless of the community's decisions. So the community can sabotage OP's intent, and OP can sabotage community's intent. Both can happen.

Comment: @ingotangjingle that's why we have moderators, they are the final arbiter of what is and isn't allowed on the site.

Comment: @RobertLongson and?

Comment: @ingotangjingle An answer can only be delete-voted by non-moderators if it has a negative score ([socre <= -1 on all sites, except MSO, which is <= -8](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295681/answer-deletion-on-meta-stack-overflow)). Voting to delete an answer also requires > 20k reputation. These are both *significant* barriers to the abuse of deletion which you appear to be claiming happens and which you appear to be proposing this feature request as a means to prevent.

Comment: @ingotangjingle "and OP can sabotage community's intent" No they can't, as Makyen pointed out ("The fact that an answer was accepted has no effect on if it can or can't be undeleted or voted to be undeleted."). *This request* would change things so that the OP can sabotage the community.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi OP decides what they accept, it's not decided by the community. That's how OP can sabotage what the community wants: Nothing prevents OP from not accepting any answers, or accepting an outdated or bad answer.

Comment: @Makyen The community decides what answers to delete, so they can delete answers OP finds most useful. OP can no longer see an answer that they found useful, even if deleted for a good reason. Nothing prevents the community from doing this, and therefore sabotaging the OP's intent.

Comment: @ingotangjingle How does that sabotage the community? Acceptance indicates *what the OP considers correct* and nothing more. It doesn't mark what the community considers correct. Why would the community want to accept ("mark as considered correct by the author") something the author does not consider correct?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi That's not the same goals as when community deletes an answer.

Comment: @ingotangjingle Well... yes? So what? Different mechanisms are used for different goals.

Comment: @ingotangjingle What? I most certainly did not. Please reread what has actually been written; if you think I would agree with everything you've written, you are majorly misreading my words. If you want to go on discussing with me, please clarify why you keep on asserting I would agree with everything you said. I consider such a unilateral misrepresentation of my opinion to your advantage highly offensive.

Comment: Well IMO yes, because the acceptance feature is borderline meaningless and certainly the most often misinterpreted feature of the site. It should have no influence at all on who is capable to vote to delete an answer. But then again, I am in the camp of just removing the acceptance feature altogether and keep things nice and simple. So I'm biased.

Answer (score 15):

If an answer is dangerous - maybe it's got some kind of hidden malware in it or running it would non-obviously delete data then those answers need to be removed. Moderators may not have the necessary subject matter knowledge of the programming language to determine that so it's up to subject matter experts to help out and do it for them.

Sometimes the OP may accept a perverse or rude answer or something that isn't an answer at all. We shouldn't allow two users acting together who may know very little about how the site should work to override the community and prevent a very poor answer from being deleted.

Excepting moderators, it takes at least 3 users with 20K to delete an answer so it's not something that can happen very often. There's no real delete review queue either so it's ever so hard to get an answer deleted. Here on Meta Stack Overflow an answer also needs to [get to a score of -8](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295681/answer-deletion-on-meta-stack-overflow) before non-moderators can vote to delete it.

On top of that non-moderators only get one delete vote per post so if an answer has been deleted by mistake and a moderator then undeletes it, we can't vote to delete it again.

If you know of some answer that's useful and been deleted then custom flag the question, or any post at all if the question has also been deleted, and ask for a moderator to undelete things. You'll have to give the moderator some way to find the answer.

Note that the moderator will look at the answer and if it deserves to be deleted it will stay deleted.

Comment: OP accepted the answer, so I'm not sure why the community can un-accept it. Wouldn't it make more sense to just let the community handle accepting fully at that point, if the OP can lose an answer they have accepted. forever?

Comment: Sure if you accept [a rude and ranty answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/427976/1038015), we can delete it without having to wait for a moderator to notice our flags. On weekends we'd end up with such content sitting around for far too long if we were blocked from doing that.